# PanGesture with repeatable background using SpriteKit

Tags: ios, iphone, uigesturerecognizer, sprite-kit

I'm having trouble getting a repeatable background to work in my game menu.

The user can slide a finger across the screen to select a character to play. 
I have a parallax effect working with various backgrounds as the characters slide into view.

Sample below.

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view 
{
    self.pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragScene:)];
    self.pan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    self.pan.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.pan];
}

- (void)dragScene:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture 
{
    CGPoint trans = [gesture translationInView:self.view];
    SKAction *moveSky = [SKAction moveByX:trans.x*0.03 y:0 duration:0];
    [_skyBackground runAction:moveSky];
}
```

I would like to repeat the backgrounds. I know how to do this with automatically scrolling backgrounds but I can't seem to get it to work here. It needs to repeat in both directions, left and right.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How far can the player scroll? i.e. should the background be able to move infinitely in either direction?

Comment: There will be a limit to how far someone can scroll, but the limit could change at any time. Infinitely would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two more background nodes - one to the left of your current background node and one to the right. Move them aswell any time you move your existing _skyBackground node.
Then, in the update method, check if any of the three nodes needs to be "shifted" - either to behind the other two or in front. You're basically swapping the three nodes' positions if needed.

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {

    //get the left background node (or if using an ivar just use _leftNode)
    SKSpriteNode *leftNode = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName:@"leftNode"];

    //my positioning might be off but you'll get the idea
    if (leftNode.position.x < -leftNode.size.width*2)
    {
        leftNode.position = CGPointMake(leftNode.size.width, leftNode.position.y);
    }

    if (leftNode.position.x > leftNode.size.width*2)
    {
        leftNode.position = CGPointMake(-leftNode.size.width, leftNode.position.y);
    }

    //repeat the same for _skyBackground and _rightNode

}
```

You may need more than 3 images if there's a slight gap between images as they're shifted.